# Using import fs from 'fs'

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I want to use `import fs from 'fs'` in JavaScript. Here is a sample:

```
import fs from 'fs'

var output = fs.readFileSync('someData.txt')

console.log(output)
```

The error I get when I run my file using `node main.js` is:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import fs from 'fs
'
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

What should I install in Node.js in order to achieve importing modules and functions from other places?

Comment: A transpiler. Or the next node release from the future.

Comment: Look at my answer to get it working!

Comment: While Node 14 allows (for example) `import fs from 'fs/promises'` syntax, on earlier versions, you'll have to create an alias using `import { promises as fs } from syntax`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[ES6 modules support](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) in Node.js is fairly recent; even in the bleeding-edge versions, it is still experimental. With Node.js 10, you can start Node.js with the `--experimental-modules` flag, and it will likely work.

To import on older Node.js versions - or standard Node.js 10 - use [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) syntax:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: The answer from RobertoNovelo would be the better choice if you really want to use ES6 imports.

Comment: You can use `--experimental-modules` from node v8.5. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/esm.html

Answer (score 206):

For default exports you should use:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

Or in case the module has named exports:

```
import {fs} from 'fs';
```

Example:

```
//module1.js

export function function1() {
  console.log('f1')
}

export function function2() {
  console.log('f2')
}

export default function1;
```

And then:

```
import defaultExport, { function1, function2 } from './module1'

defaultExport();  // This calls function1
function1();
function2();
```

Additionally, you should use [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) or something similar to be able to use [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) `import`

Comment: This does not work because fs has neither a default export nor an export named "fs". `import fs from "fs";` is the correct syntax.

Comment: How can this incorrect answer have so many upvotes? Please update this answer in accordance with the comment from @KonradHöffner above.

Comment: @rinogo Callback and async APIs are imported via `import * as fs from 'fs';`, and the promise-based APIs via `import * as fs from 'fs/promises';`. `fs` supports both CommonJS syntax and ES6 Modules. Can you provide an example usage with `import fs from "fs";` ? Also, the rest of the answer is just an example of how you can export/import functions and defaults.

Comment: @RobertoNovelo Yeah, I'm not sure what's going on - on second look, I *am* using the syntax you've recommended. However, I clearly felt strong enough to upvote Konrad's comment and add a comment of my own... I remember getting a syntax error in Typescript with the syntax that I'm clearly using now. I'm digging in at the moment and will report back if I figure out what's going on.

Comment: Getting this error

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: @HarshShukla are you using `import * as fs from 'fs';`? Are you running it on any special runtime such as an edge function? If so, the `fs` module might not be available unless the platform provides it for you. Additionally, `fs` is a node.js module, importing it in the front end will not work natively.

Comment: This is a bad answer because you are giving just general advice and not addressing the specific problem. Because of that it's even misleading and just wastes time.

Answer (score 60):

Building on RobertoNovelo's answer:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

is currently the simplest way to do it.

It was tested with a Node.js project (Node.js v10.15.3), with [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm#readme), allowing to use `import`.

Comment: I've v10.16.0 and it doesn't work for me giving error- `unexpected token *`

Answer (score 42):

In order to use `import { readFileSync } from 'fs'`, you have to:

1. Be using Node.js 10 or later
2. Use the `--experimental-modules` flag (in Node.js 10), e.g. `node --experimental-modules server.mjs` (see #3 for explanation of .mjs)
3. Rename the file extension of your file with the `import` statements, to `.mjs`, *.js will not work*, e.g. server.mjs

The other answers hit on 1 and 2, but 3 is also necessary.  Also, note that this feature is considered extremely experimental at this point (1/10 stability) and not recommended for production, but I will still probably use it.

Here's the [Node.js 10 ESM documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

Answer (score 9):

Go to package.json file and add:

```
"type": "module"
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

It is 2023, In the current version node 16+:

```js
import {readFileSync} from "fs"

const string_output = readFileSync("path-to-file", 'utf8')
// the rest
```

If you do not give the second argument, encoding 'utf8', it will return a binary file

Answer (score 2):

If we are using TypeScript, we can update the type definition file by running the command `npm install @types/node` from the terminal or command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The new ECMAScript module support is able natively in Node.js 12

It was released on 2019-04-23 and it means there is no need to use the flag `--experimental-modules`.

To read more about it:

*[The new ECMAScript module support in Node.js 12](http://2ality.com/2019/04/nodejs-esm-impl.html)*

Comment: This is not true, in node v12.11.1 the flag is still required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your statement import fs from 'fs' to be executable, you can make your file extension .mjs instead of .js.
i.e filename.mjs

Answer (score -1):

It's not supported just yet... If you want to use it you will have to install [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/).

Answer (score -2):

hey friends node js use commonjs not modaljs so use alawys use
const fs = require('fs') for file system if we use modaljs import fs from 'fs'
its give error se in termile
import {fs} from 'fs';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module