# module not found importing function of npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
//something.spec.js
import { myCustomGlob } from './scripts/index'
describe.only('generate index', () => {
    console.log(myCustomGlob) //MODULE NOT FONUD ERROR
})

//script
const fs = require('fs')
const myCustomGlob = () => {
    //some fs operation
}
export {
    myCustomGlob
}
```

I have a npm script that used glob and fs to generate some code to create a new file. But I want to write unit test for those function too, but I got MODULE 'fs' NOT FOUND error. why? I thought 'fs' is included since I import myCustomGlob?

Comment: You are using type script that's new for me but i can see you are using two types syntax for import module in you page. So kindly check your fs importing syntax may be incorrect.

Comment: @Devrajverma does it matter? I can run the script using npm run. The problem is my spec file.

Comment: @Devrajverma that's not typeScript , @melissa92 try : `import {fs} from 'fs';` instead of `import 'fs' from 'fs'`

Comment: @melissa92 you also can use const fs = rquire('fs') instead of import 'fs' from 'fs' .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using import fs from 'fs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622337/using-import-fs-from-fs)

Comment: @Taki thanks for correct me. But syntax are looking same as type script.

Comment: @Taki that's not the problem, the problem is at my spec.js

Answer (score 0):

Try `import * as fs from 'fs'` or just try removing the quotes from the first `fs`. You are looking up the module with a string, that doesn't work.

Comment: it's not about the import in my script, it's error from spec file.

Comment: Well the error clearly has something to do with the spec script not being able to find the module it needs. I wrote this before the person asking the question changed her code, it was still relevant then. Although I think it's still relevant because the error says it can't find the module it needs.

Comment: @Evelijn exactly

Comment: @Melissa92 So have you tried a actually importing fs module in the spec? The spec needs it too in order to know what fs is.

Comment: @Evelijn tried that of course, same error. Not sure it has to do with my karma config, so far I haven't have that kind of error at all.

Comment: Have you also defined fs in the karma config?

Comment: @Melissa92 sorry I forgot to mention you. So fs as a dependency in the karma config, have you tried that?

Comment: I found the issue, it was because I ignore node_module, because I use to test mostly frontend code which doesn't require node_module at all, but when you have something that use fs, path, and glob, you would want to use that, not sure if I should customize the karma config to use node_module for this single test only.

Comment: @Melissa92 Ah that makes sense, nice catch! I think the matter of customizing the karma config is something you should decide for yourself. If this is indeed the only test you need node_modules for, chances are such a exception is sufficient.

Comment: @Evelijn I'm testing npm script which generate a bunch of code, does it make sense to even test the function for it? it doesn't seem the logic will fail, and I don't think will add more codes to the script in the future, it's strange to test that isn't it? most likely it will never fail.