# JS cannot import npm module

Tags: javascript, html, npm, import, module

I can't import npm module using for example `import fs from 'fs';` in my main.js file that linked with index.html.
Script tag that connect JS file has attribute `type="module"`.
Error in console of browser throws error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`.
BUT npm modules must be connected by pointing only module name, without path and I already did that in another project and it worked correctly.

Then I tried to point relative path to fs module. But node_modules doesn't have folder 'fs'. Instead it contains several folders with 'fs' in start of each folder name.

At that moment I was completely confused :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import it as `import * as fs from 'fs';`. You may also have problems with `fs` import in the web, but that's a different issue.

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622337/using-import-fs-from-fs)

EDIT: The question was "Cannot import npm module". As pointed out by Michael Flores in comment and suggested in the original answer, this won't work anyway in web as `fs` is not module you can install - it's part of Node.JS

Comment: You *will* have problems attempting an `fs` import in code running in the browser, because the module comes from Node. Changing his import to `import * as fs from 'fs'` will do nothing for his error.

Answer (score 0):

`fs` is a module available when running on a Node server, not in the browser.